# E: Unable to locate package guile-2.2 linux mint

Tags: linux, package, guile

- I needed to install guile-2.2 on my machine (with linuxMint).
- but when I type command `(sudo apt-get install guile-2.2)`. it gives me the following error.
- `E: Unable to locate package guile-2.2`
- can someone help, please!

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: this question is about development. what else is it about? I think you are not familiar with functional programming area.

Comment: Try [how do I search for package using apt](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+do+I+search+for+package+using+apt). I could be wrong, but I don't think it has anything to do with programming or development. Perhaps you can edit the question and make its programming elements more obvious.

Comment: The ball got dropped. I also Googled to no avail. The solution is finding & installing all the dependencies and then building Guile.